# Return a promise for a simple action creator in react using react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to the react-redux . Here , I think this is a very basic question. But , I have a action creator, and I am using a redux thunk.

```
export const updateActivePage = (activePage) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE,
    payload: activePage
  }
}
```

what I tried is

```
export const updateActivePage = (activePage) => (dispatch) => {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE,
      payload: activePage
    })
  })
}
```

the function after then is not getting called.

Now, in my `componentdidmount` In want to use  `.then` after this

So, for that I want to return a promise . So,How can I do this ? I am using the `reux-thunk`

Comment: This is not an async operation, no point to use promise. Simply write your next command into the next row.

Comment: Read about async actions - https://alligator.io/redux/redux-thunk/

Comment: If I add it in the second line then will it get the updated props value for the next row action

Answer (score 0):

Promises are rather used when you want to fetch some data from external source (like REST). However, if you really want to do this, a action creator has to return a function:

```
export const updateActivePage = (activePage) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch ({
      type: UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE,
      payload: activePage
    });
  }
}
```

Something like this should return promise. 
However, this promise will be resolved when action is dispatched. It's not the same as redux state change. I think that you don't really want to use promise here.

If you want to react when something in redux state changes, your component should observe the state (using mapStateToProps) and you can handle changes in `componentWillUpdate` method.

Comment: I tried this as well. but it is saying its not a function

Comment: this.props.updateActivePage(...).then is not a function

Comment: Are you sure that Thunk is working at all? Do you see UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE action dispatched and handled by a reducer? Maybe you have a problem with configuration?

Comment: handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    this.props.updateActivePage(pageNumber).then(() => {
        this.props.fetchUserJd(this.props.activePage - 1);
    });
  }

Comment: thunk shouldn't be used that way. Just use componentWillReceiveProps: `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ this.props.fetchUserJd(nextProps.activePage - 1); }`

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [redux-thunk readme](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk):

```
function makeASandwichWithSecretSauce(forPerson) {
  // We can invert control here by returning a function - the "thunk".
  // When this function is passed to `dispatch`, the thunk middleware will intercept it,
  // and call it with `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments. 
  // This gives the thunk function the ability to run some logic, and still interact with the store.
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchSecretSauce().then(
      sauce => dispatch(makeASandwich(forPerson, sauce)),
      error => dispatch(apologize('The Sandwich Shop', forPerson, error))
    );
  };
}

...

// It even takes care to return the thunk’s return value
// from the dispatch, so I can chain Promises as long as I return them.

store.dispatch(
  makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My partner')
).then(() => {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```